# How can an atomic operation be not a synchronization operation?

Tags: c++, concurrency, atomic

The standard says that a relaxed atomic operation is not a synchronization operation. But what's atomic about an operation result of which is not seen by other threads.

The example [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/fetch_add) wouldn't give the expected result then, right?

What I understand by synchronization is that the result of an operation with such trait would be visible by all threads.

Maybe I don't understand what synchronization means.
Where's the hole in my logic?

Comment: Not synchronizing with respect to _other_ operations. The (result of the) operation itself is always observed by other threads.

Comment: @LWimsey so synchronization is achieved with memory barriers(but it's called ordering...)? It's not clear what you mean by synchronization with _other_ operations.

Comment: "Synchronize-with" has a specific technical meaning in C++, in terms of creating a "happens-before" relationship between earlier code in one thread (e.g. before a release store) and later code in another thread (often with an acquire load).  https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler and the CPU are allowed to reorder memory accesses. It's the [as-if rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718262/what-exactly-is-the-as-if-rule) and it assumes a single-threaded process.

In multithreaded programs, the memory order parameter specifies how memory accesses are to be ordered *around* an atomic operation. This is the synchronization aspect (the "acquire-release semantics") of an atomic operation that is separate from the atomicity aspect itself:

```
int x = 1;
std::atomic<int> y = 1;

    // Thread 1
    x++;
    y.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_release);

    // Thread 2
    while ((y.load(std::memory_order_acquire) == 1)
    { /* wait */ }
    std::cout << x << std::endl;  // x is 2 now
```

Whereas with a relaxed memory order we only get atomicity, but not ordering:

```
int x = 1;
std::atomic<int> y = 1;

    // Thread 1
    x++;
    y.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);

    // Thread 2
    while ((y.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == 1)
    { /* wait */ }
    std::cout << x << std::endl;  // x can be 1 or 2, we don't know
```

Indeed as Herb Sutter explains in his excellent [atomic<> weapons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A8eCGOqgvH4) talk, `memory_order_relaxed` makes a multithreaded program very difficult to reason about and should be used in very specific cases only, when there is no dependency between the atomic operation and *any other operation* before or after it in any thread (very rarely the case).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, standard is correct. Relaxed atomics are not synchronization operation, as only atomicity of operation is guaranteed.

For example,

```
int k = 5;
void foo() {
    k = 10;
}

int baz() {
    return k;
}
```

In presence of multiple threads, the behavior is undefined as it exposes race condition. In practice on some architectures it could happen that a caller of `baz` would see nor 10, no 5, but some other, indeterminate value. It is often called *torn* or *dirty* read.

If a relaxed atomic load and store was used instead `baz` would be guaranteed to return either 5 or 10, as there would be no data race.

It is worth noting that for practical purposes, Intel chips and their very strong memory model make relaxed atomic a noop (meaning there is no extra cost for it being atomic) on this common architecture, as loads and stores are atomic on hardware level.

Comment: On X86, compared to non-atomic operations, there is extra cost for (relaxed) atomic operations because a compiler cannot apply the same level of optimization. For example, an atomic store is always committed to L1-cache (for visibility reasons) while it could stay inside a CPU register if non-atomic.

Comment: @LWimsey not true.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have

```
std::atomic<int> x = 0;

// thread 1
foo();
x.store(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);

// thread 2
assert(x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == 1);
bar();
```

There is, first of all, no guarantee that thread 2 will observe the value 1 (that is, the assert may fire). But even if thread 2 does observe the value 1, while thread 2 is executing `bar()`, it might not observe side effects generated by `foo()` in thread 1. And if `foo()` and `bar()` access the same non-atomic variables, a data race may occur.

Now suppose we change the example to:

```
std::atomic<int> x = 0;

// thread 1
foo();
x.store(1, std::memory_order_release);

// thread 2
assert(x.load(std::memory_order_acquire) == 1);
bar();
```

There is still no guarantee that thread 2 observes the value 1; after all, it could happen that the load occurs before the store. However, in this case, *if* thread 2 observes the value 1, then the store in thread 1 synchronizes with the load in thread 2. What this means is that everything that's sequenced before the store in thread 1 happens before everything that's sequenced after the load in thread 2. Therefore, `bar()` will see all the side effects produced by `foo()` and if they both access the same non-atomic variables, no data race will occur.

So, as you can see, the synchronization properties of operations on `x` tell you nothing about what happens to `x`. Instead, synchronization imposes ordering on *surrounding* operations in the two threads. (Therefore, in the linked example, the result is always 5, and does not depend on the memory ordering; the synchronization properties of the fetch-add operations don't affect the effect of the fetch-add operations themselves.)

Comment: you say in the second example if both `bar()`  and `foo()` access the same non-atomic, no data race will occur. Well, if they happen to change this non-atomic variable in the same time(which is possible?), then there's a race condition by definition

Comment: @DanA. I said that "everything that's sequenced before the store in thread 1 happens before everything that's sequenced after the load in thread 2" --- therefore things that happen in `foo()` are not potentially concurrent with things that happen in `bar()`.